# Active Storage public_url not returning key/filename.extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

The public option is added to Active Storage in this PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36729 
In it he clearly says: *"In the public bucket, the directory structure is /[key]/[filename]"*

Which makes sense and is exactly what I want. I want to be able (for example) to email the link to someone and allow them to download the file. So I need the filename.extension. But when I spin up a Rails 6.1 app the uploads to my bucket do not have the filename after them.
The files do appear in my bucket, but only as their key. Not key/filename.

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: us-east-1
  bucket: mybucket
  public: true
```

The uploading works fine. The files are uploaded and appear in my bucket. But in the view `<%= @user.avatar.url %>` returns `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/g3ci2umbfj6wkxyggx7arhekxfib` I *want* it to return `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/g3ci2umbfj6wkxyggx7arhekxfib/myfile.png`
This is really annoying me because in the PR the author clearly states that the public files are saved as key/filename.extension

So the question: In Rails 6.1 does the `url` method return the filename as part of the path or not. And if not why does the author say that it does? And if not is there a better way than patching `key`?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

```
= link_to @user.avatar.filename, rails_blob_path(@user.avatar, disposition: "course.avatar"), target: :_blank
```

will give you a download link like `https://corsego-production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/3gbpl68kckpkyrbjoslsl254th0u?response-content-disposition=inline&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEGgaCmV1LBuuKkri8zL3ohM4h9STzhTsnavAgulrcpBavL0POXg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20201002T170820Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA5RINJ20201002%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0a205d713ebaa9d3ca9d62`

---

`@user.avatar.url` is not supposed to return anything!

`@user.avatar` is supposed to return something like `#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007f15986ee4c0>`

When creating an attachment with Active Storage, the following fields about the attachment are automatically populated and saved as `active_storage_blobs`:

```
  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end
```

Let's say you upload an image with active storage. The above Table will be populated in a following way:

```
Id: 1
Key: sy2y1ytw7zob6mwtnwc1552cdp5l
Filename: Screenshot 2020-10-02 125405.png
Content_type: image/png
Metadata: {"identified"=>true, "analyzed"=>true}
Byte_size: 1550
Checksum: mGPerbRMj6LXbPKhqKd4bA
```

To display the user avatar as an image, you must call `= image_tag @user.avatar`

`= rails_blob_url(@user.avatar)` will give you something like `https://example.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--5fb10a9c8e9f2c4e7099eee21c1dc2ff0343c210/Screenshot%202020-10-02%20125405.png`

`= @user.avatar` will give you something like `#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007f1589293dd0>`

`= url_for(@user.avatar)` will give you something like `/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--5fb10a9c8e9f2c4e7099eee21c1dc2ff0343c210/Screenshot%202020-10-02%20125405.png`

The second table in the migrations created by active_storage is this:

```
  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end
```

basically it connects the blob with a specific record in your application (basically the `avatar` is a `blob`, the `@user` is the `record`, and they are associated via the `active_storage_attachments` table.

So you can also run the following commands on the @user.avatar method:

```
@user.avatar.name #Avatar
@user.avatar.record_type #User
@user.avatar.record_id #2 (user id)
@user.avatar.blob_id #1 (blob id)
```

[image]

Now, below is an example url to the above file stored on AWS S3:
[https://corsego-production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/3gbpl68kckpkyrbjoslsl254th0u?response-content-disposition=inline&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEGgaCmRzBFAiBSJ2QIEqs1opj%2BuCR74CDMt67ueDTTQIhAOJGGy2wfmxmGUwpQe9cyc84ZhUhuWKHdVgTUctbtGrVKdinkpg0w7OikcyNYpnbq%2FefcTmEgRvIlPO%2B0itFxUr8mKUvnDYSuKkri8zL3ohM4h9STzhTsnavAgulrcpBavL0POXg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20201002T170820Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA5RINJLY2F20201002%2Feu-central-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0a205d713ebaaa339ad4ee09db9dfe16986e69d3ca9d62](https://corsego-production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/3gbpl68kckpkyrbjoslsl254th0u?response-content-disposition=inline&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEGgaCmV1LW5vcnRoLTEiRzBFAiBSJ2QIEqs1opj%2BuCR74OAarvsl2bs867CDMt67ueDTTQIhAOJGGy2wfmxmGUwpQe9cyc84ZhUhuWKHdVgTUctbtGrVKs0CCJL%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQABoMOTMwNDI1MTY3MzcyIgz1nDblPaTiLbAiG08qoQIMABAVVGY5V35b1QLNo7s0Zek%2FKZlXXkpLkMPmW2IgBMRR8KRN926548wCqXpncarWqDYxSjNA07%2B5eTdW%2F9z9OYbJaqcUDWPsS9FhWwrVWlio48wvakrPpzETs0g7mEFv4ft1%2Fwh7P2PyqUGuQEdweBaIPkyz6JKWGPybLZGQvPyyV9Ql%2Frt8bOxBQ6XoAEEkKCnS1984CQOuu75h1b2%2F%2Fm5GTv6wokjm8bA3L04Vz2Gps2gpE%2FOkRSeboGt8Psgh7LXMUu1QwzAN9FYLj3hxNSYsqMJuYdCmO9pGIx1uIpfpk07Mc3Mpk0N9aV3h%2BN3elxRCuHe7shdQkA7r%2BAb31YcyD4ng6YL0oWgJIbZqGCjL76M3VCA0WDGHom8a7tkuMO352%2FsFOrACRTd5s5NmCATNRrbYJaH84pi3%2FcPH7ElN5LdmlGtjnW%2FsURteeVb8Ii7PrjoBxSQ%2FdMQUf9SzUbtgpWPlNXaxt58lFw%2BN2soaWhuixXHp%2BnVA90Hm6RW2EkQbQsgwO4BSleopgRfhTtlO7vKBfnuC3D06cTdsgSSSX8lkgutmLKmWQoMq2BT27IRqZB%2FJFjAZA%2FSk77ZfNFeOnA8gZBneN5Znb06mke66Ldr9tZ%2BGbhmsXPdpJV2Ov692PJ%2BLLRhAKVZnwPl9DxyIitME3v%2F2nMDXYFGXfeMvwzUEJImkUam5h3LsWvd2O2SoQeKdinkpg0w7OikcyNYpnbq%2FefcTmEgRvIlPO%2B0itFxUr8mKUvnDYSuKkri8zL3ohM4h9STzhTsnavAgulrcpBavL0POXg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20201002T170820Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA5RINJLYGA67KSSGA%2F20201002%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0a205d713ebaaa339add784dad3f45f61d84a4ee09db9dfe16986e69d3ca9d62)

See how the url contains a secret token and an expiry time? It is advised not to have permanent urls to files.

P.S. When connecting AWS S3 to your application, don't forget to add [CORS configuration](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-configuration):
[image]

Comment: This is a thorough answer, but didn't address my question. My question is about Rails 6.1 public service PR.

Comment: Ok looks like I understood the goal of your question differently :) Anyway, did you find an answer?