# AWS S3 direct upload from rails backend results in S3 bucket items with hex names and no file extensions

Tags: amazon-s3, backend, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

Anyone have this issue with S3 where the files you store from your rails backend don't show up with the filename you specify in the attach method? For example:

```
    book.epub.attach(io: File.open("<filepath>/tangrenjie.epub"), filename: "rangrenjie.epub", content_type: 'application/epub+zip')
```

This results in the file having its name as "qsqyksxtpq66uk6vvyn6mtam17cp" on S3:

[image: here's a screenshot of what the bucket looks like; the bucket is public and all the links download when you click each one, but anything requiring a src url doesn't work]

I uploaded one manually on the S3 console and everything actually worked. its name wasn't changed which leads to me to think it's an issue from rails to S3.

I tried adding to the CORS tab on S3; but I'm not sure what I would put since

1. rails sends credentials and the files do get to S3 and
2. I don't think localhost counts as a domain

It wouldn't be a problem, but the dependencies I'm using need a public url -- the url for the file I uploaded manually on S3 works (of course), but everything from my rails app ends up getting a giant key as its file name without any file extension (see screenshot) and they don't work when I use them as src url's in my app.

I've gone through guides like https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#s3-service-amazon-s3-and-s3-compatible-apis

I've been getting help from the author of the dependency I'm using, but he has no idea as he hasn't used S3 in a while.

here's the current CORS rule I have in S3:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I'm using rails 6.0.3 as an api with ActiveStorage along with the AWS S3 service, using the aws-sdk-s3 gem, using root user credentials to store files associated with objects on the rails backend app.

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64071695/active-storage-public-url-not-returning-key-filename-extension/64175761#64175761) - most likely it fully answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Yshmarov! That helped a bit. As it goes, I should avoid changing the keys/using public buckets.