# Rich_text and Active Storage S3 Uploads are returning 200 but not uploading the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am having some issues with rich_text and Active Storage's s3 attachments. The attachments just hang and never actually upload, no files in S3 bucket. When I attach, I get this response:

```
Started POST "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" for ::1 at 2020-11-18 07:15:08 -0800
Processing by ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"blob"=>{"filename"=>"[FILTERED]", "content_type"=>"application/pdf", "byte_size"=>72922, "checksum"=>"fsKWzt9ogXiN21nveUYF5g=="}, "direct_upload"=>{"blob"=>{"filename"=>"[FILTERED]", "content_type"=>"application/pdf", "byte_size"=>72922, "checksum"=>"fsKWzt9ogXiN21nveUYF5g=="}}}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (13.2ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "[present]"], ["filename", "Approved Lenders Washington 6.18.pdf"], ["content_type", "application/pdf"], ["byte_size", 72922], ["checksum", "fsKWzt9ogXiN21nveUYF5g=="], ["created_at", "2020-11-18 15:15:09.182618"]]
   (22.5ms)  COMMIT
  S3 Storage (2.5ms) Generated URL for file at key: [present] (https://[bucket-name].s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/...)
Completed 200 OK in 1024ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 48.9ms | Allocations: 150095)
```

My model, storage.yml & development.rb:

```
model.rb
class Exercise
  has_rich_text :description
end

storage.yml
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: us-west-2
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :bucket_name) %>

development.rb
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

Any ideas of what can be going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Add model

Comment: did you add CORS config in AWS?

Comment: See my answer here. Possibly it will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64071695/active-storage-public-url-not-returning-key-filename-extension/64175761#64175761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS configuration was not properly formatted in the S3 bucket. I modified the CORS configuration to below:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```